# Regex - Match URL Path But Exclude Final Slash (If It Is Present)

Tags: regex

I have a url path that can take the form of starting with `/api/` at the beginning of the path string and then it can take any valid path form, such as:

```
/api/test
/api/test/
/api/test/best/
/api/test/best
...etc
```

Which I want to give:

```
test
test
test/best
test/best
```

Meaning, I want a regex to give me everything after `/api/` but EXCLUDE the final slash in the path (if there is one). By this I mean the final slash that would exist if it was the final terminating character in the string - not the final `/` in the string itself (note the fourth example has no qualifying `/` under this condition - it ends in a `t` (the end of `bes"t"`) not a terminating slash to the whole string).

I've gotten close but not exactly what I wanted. I either always get terminating slash included or I get a situation where it stops after the first `/` it finds in the string (note the url could have multiple slashes separating multiple terms in the path after `api`, not just two terms).

Please also suggest an answer that would not work if the path didn't start with `/api/`, thank you!

Comment: What about `\/api\/(.+)\/?` or for a full string match `^\/api\/(.+)\/?$`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I made a test of your regex here - https://regexr.com/59cos - it returns the trailing slash

Comment: You didn't want the /api/ or trailing slash matched so match group 1 contains just the part between.  So I thought you would just use match group 1.  But if you want the whole match to not include those parts matbe a look around is the answer.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah in that regex tester the terminating trailing slash gets included in group 1 when applying your answer. i believe it needs a look around but unsure how to do one that will work.

Comment: It includes the /api/ and trailing slash because it shows the whole match and not the group 1 match.  This regex matches all but the last slash (but includes the /api/ part): `.*(?<!\/)`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Ah, so `\/api\/(.*)(?<!\/)` would include just the part I want in the group 1! Thank you so much! If you want to create an answer I can accept it. :)

Comment: What about `(?<=\/api\/)(.*)(?<!\/)` Does it do even better what you want?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah seems to be good, not sure how it acts differently though from my previous answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/api/(.*?)/?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PiFihh/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%2Fapi%2F(.*%3F)%2F%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `/api/` - a substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string

**An alternative** is to match all chars up to the last non-slash char:

```
/api/(.*[^/])
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PiFihh/2). Here, `(.*[^/])` captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last char other than `/`.

Answer (score -1):

following regex will do as you want:

`\/api\/.*?(?=$|\/$)`

**Detail:**

`\/api\/`: match `/api/` url part

`.*?`: match as much as it can non-greedy

`(?=$|\/$)` final character can be end of line or trailing slash, using positive look-ahead with non-greedy match will do as you want

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SZX75O/3/)